# Primefaces scrolling to first message in hided tab

Tags: primefaces, tabview

I am using some simple tabviews with a lot of inputs. When I am submitting, I want to scroll the view to the first error. I am using simple Jquery and everythinks works fine, but the problem is when the first error is showed in tab (for exmaple 2), and this tab is hidden (tab 1 is showed). In this case ui-message return some wired value of offset, but even it would return good value it would scroll to hided tab. Some solutions?

Code:

```
$('html').animate({scrollTop: (($('.ui-message-error').first().offset().top) - 10)}, 500);



<p:tabView id="tabview">
      <p:tab id="tab1" title="1">
         <p:inputText id="value1" value="#{bean.value1}" required="true"
         ...
      </p:tab>
      <p:tab id="tab1" title="2">
         <p:inputText id="value2" value="#{bean.value2}" required="true"
         ...
      </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Second how to bind this javascript to all buttons? Maybe jquery click event on some class .submit-button or so? But I think it is called before action listeners of buttons will complete, so its not good.

Comment: One way to go, check in jQuery if that message is inside a hidden tab if so show it and scroll

Comment: Ye i ve made it, but i though there is some better solution. Anyway now i wonder how to bind this jquery to every submit buttons? I thought about some css class on submit button and jquerry click event but i need to call this method after button action listener ll complete.